# Can I jail an older 32-bit FreeBSD on a (current) 64-bit FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, jails

Is it possible to jail an older 32-bit FreeBSD, such as 6.4 or 8.4 in a 64-bit FreeBSD 10.2?

I'll also appreciate pointers and explanations on how to accomplish this and information on what prerequisites my host needs to fulfill.

NB: according to [this blog article](http://blather.michaelwlucas.com/archives/1919), jailing an older FreeBSD on a current one is possible. But that article makes no mention of 32-bit versus 64-bit.

Comment: it seems other people have been worrying about it too https://gundersen.net/32bit-jail-on-64bit-freebsd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMPAT_FREEBSD32 needs to be enabled in your FreeBSD kernel (It is enabled in the GENERIC kernel)

There might be problems with the 32bit ps and top programs.